# summing values in columns with the dynamic columns and rows php

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get the sum of all the fields in columns. where columns are dynamic even the rows are dynamic. (with date wise record filter).

Hi.. here in my table the user can add column's dynamically, so i won't be knowing the columns name to raw code initially as $row['SUM(price)']. Hence I need a query which can pull by itself all the column values.

id  s_id    topic   day date            subject Anushka Bharath Chetan
1   1   Dr.Jain Sun 25-03-2011  anusha   0  1   1
2   2   Ori-Par Mon 07-01-2013  accounts 1  0   0
3   3   ori-stu mon 09-01-2013  ACCOUNTS 1  0   1

Here the table heading i.e student names are dynamic and I am adding the attendance data of each students. I want to calculate(sum and average) the students attendance monthly or date wise.
Please let me known if you need anything else to assist me...

Thanks in advance

Comment: `http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far? Show us some code.

Comment: "echo "Total ". $row['type']. " = $". $row['SUM(price)'];" here the 'price' is dynamic.how do i do?

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the code, so it's readable. Also, look over the FAQ, there are some suggestions on how to write a proper question. PS: Being your first question, people are willing to let one slide, but your next questions will have to meet a minimum of quality and readability.

Comment: Hi.. here in my table the user can add column's dynamically, so i won't be knowing the columns name to raw code initially as $row['SUM(price)']. Hence I need a query which can pull by itself all the column values.

Comment: @IndudharaGs First question here, please read [How to ask Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) esp, what to do when you get answers.

Comment: Share the Table Schema... and explain the fields if necessary.

Comment: updated the question with table and fields